# How to set Eclipse IDE Tab Switching settings

Tags: eclipse, settings

When I want to switch between tabs, I'd normally press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to cycle through the tabs.. and as w/ Netbean, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> Tabbing again cycles back..

It lets me jump to and from 2 scripts quicky.. but with Eclipse this doesnt work.. it's a huge huge thing for me and I wish i could set it. :(

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has that same functionality but instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a persistent problem they are currently working on:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=206299

Next Editor key shortcut is the appropriate choice for the behaviour you describe, but I cannot get it to work on my machine.  Ctrl+Tab switches to active the toolbar, and the side panels.  Apparently it was on purpose, and modifying the key binding don't appear to change this behaviour.

I'm running Eclipse 4.2.1.